# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\alpha-y}x^{m-1}e^{-\mu x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Let $f(x)$ be the function defined by
$$f(x)=x^{m-1}e^{-\mu x}$$

where $m$ is positive integer and $\mu$ is positive real number.

I would like to compute

$$
I=\int_{x=0}^{\alpha-y}f(x)dx=\int_{x=0}^{\alpha-y}x^{m-1}e^{-\mu x}dx.
$$

where $y\in[0,\infty[$

So is it 
$$I=\int_{x=0}^{\alpha-y}f(x)=\frac{\gamma\Big(m,\mu(\alpha-y)\Big)}{\mu^m}$$

or do we need the condition that $y\leq \alpha$?

Thanks.

Comment: if $m$ is a positive integer then the computation is exact, just use integration by parts

Comment: Why would we need $y\le\alpha$? This is just a u-sub and the definition of the lower incomplete gamma function.

Comment: But is not possible integration from $0$ to negative number???

Comment: If you switch the bounds you change the sign of the integral

Comment: $$\int_a^b f(t)dt=-\int_b^a f(t)dt$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^{\alpha-y}x^{m-1}e^{-\mu x}dx$$
by letting $u=\mu x$ we get:
$$I=\int_0^{\mu(\alpha-y)}\left(\frac{u}{\mu}\right)^{m-1}e^{-u}\frac{du}{\mu}=\mu^{-m}\int_0^{\mu(\alpha-y)}u^{m-1}e^{-u}du$$
and since the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) is defined as:
$$\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^xt^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
we can say that:
$$I=\mu^{-m}\gamma\bigl(m,\mu(\alpha-y)\bigr)$$
Which agrees with what you have said. I believe if we were to extend it from $x$ to $z\in\mathbb{C}$ there are then conditions added, where $\Re(m)>1$, however this is similar as is for the real domain. As for the limits of the integral, the only notatable point I think is that as $(\alpha-y)\to-\infty,I\to\infty$ and it will give negative values in $x$, giving a complex result, however this depends on the value of $m$

Answer (score 1):

For negative $\alpha -y$, the integral is taken over negative values of $x$.

For negative $x$ , the integrand function is defined over the reals, iff $m$ is a integer, as you specify.

So you do not have any limitation onto $y$, when this is real.